# ser.read() works, but ser.readLine() throws error

Tags: python, serialization, arduino, pyserial

I am attempting to read serial values from an Arduino using Python.

```
>>> ser.read()
'2'
>>> a = ser.readLine()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Serial' object has no attribute 'readLine'
```

Why do I get an error with readLine, but not with read()? Or read(10)?

The complete code I'm using:

```
>>> import serial
>>> ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbmodem1411', 9600, timeout=10)
>>> ser.read()
'\n'
>>> ser.readLine()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Serial' object has no attribute 'readLine'
>>> ser.read()
'2'
>>> ser.readLine()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Serial' object has no attribute 'readLine'
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'Serial' object has no attribute 'readLine'` implies that `readLine` is simply something that has not been implemeted

Comment: `.readLine` isn't very Pythonic. Is there a `.readline` method?

Comment: http://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shortintro.html
I'm following these examples.

Comment: @JeremyG Those examples do not use `readLine`.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks @Goyo for pointing out my silly mistake.

.readLine() is not a method, but .readline() is. Oops.

```
>>> ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbmodem1411', 9600)
>>> ser.readline()
'2456.05\r\n'
```

Comment: This code will not work if there is a newline character in the message. `GET A PROTOCOL`